# How to create a realistic sun lens flare using photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects, blur

Using `Photoshop`, i'd like to create a realistic sun `lens flare`, like the one shown on this picture :

[image]

What I have already tried : draw a `white circle`, then apply `radial blur` effect multiple times, but results are poor and not convincing.

Comment: Better lens flare effects can be achieved via : http://www.redgiant.com/products/all/knoll-light-factory-ps/ But it's not free.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Lens Flare filter is a pretty simple way to make a lens flare.

Filters > Render > Lens Flare

But in order to get a look more like the one you provided, I used to lens flare filter and made sure the brightness was set pretty low (around 75%) to make sure there isn't a lot of blur that could disrupt the next step.

Next, I just used the smudge tool to make bright spokes protrude from the center of the lens flare. This process can be quite tedious and lengthy depending on what kind of look you're aiming for. Make sure the smudge mode is on Normal.

I then made another layer ontop, used the bucket tool, and filled in the top layer and set that layer to Overlay mode to make the image pop out more.

You can play with it from there.

When doing lens flare, i try to avoid any blurring at all for it ruins the pristine look and removes the crisp glare.

Here's the results of the above steps (sorry if it's sloppy, I slapped it together quickly.) :

[image: http://imgur.com/w7UEuHK]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Lens flare filter

Filters > Render > Lens Flare

It may take a bit of playing around to make it look more realistic, but for a quick effect it works pretty well

[image: Lens Flare Filter]

Answer (score 0):

can get this effect using brushes- http://browse.deviantart.com/art/Stars-and-lights-brushes-88084815 or u need to do it manually playing around with multiple layers, lens flare effect and glow ..

Answer (score -4):

Just try Ctrl + F.
Bonjour, essayes juste avec Ctrl + F.